# how to install Longene linux unified kernel?

Tags: 13.10, windows, kernel

I heard that [Longene](http://www.longene.org) *Linux unified kernel* ([Sourceforge link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/longene/)) ([GibHub link](https://github.com/tsuibin/longene)) will help me install windows apps and some people say it [performs better than regular Wine](http://www.linuxtoday.com/developer/2010060303135OSKNDV). I need to use windows apps on my Ubuntu 13.10 . I have tried play on Linux and wine but they wont work for my needs. Please tell me how to install that Linux unified kernel

Comment: Checkout this link from the developer about installing longene (the software required to run it) http://www.longene.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=4218&p=10085#p10085

Comment: Looks interesting, but, IMO the bottom line is such projects (wine, ReactOS, etc) are still in development and running complex windows applications typically fails or is buggy. Most people use KVM or Virtualbox and run a virtualized version of windows or dual boot. Linux is not a drop in replacement for Windows and IMO if your primary intention is to run windows apps, stay with windows. If you run linux, find cross platform apps or linux native apps (such as libre office).

Answer (score 0):

Longene appears to be a dead project. The source code patch is dated 2006 and last download package is dated 2010. The patch is for a very old 2.6 kernel. There is no way you will be able to install Longene on a modern Ubuntu release.

Answer (score 0):

[longene-1.0-rc2](http://www.longene.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=16083) has the instruction on how to build and install longene kernel module. After that, you can run Windows application on your Linux machine. But the kernel module can only be built on x86 machine, x64 is not supported yet.